# apache spark: Need inputs to optimize my code

Tags: apache-spark

I am building a application which reads 1.5 G data and translates. My code skeleton is as follows.

//here i pass a list of id’s to read 4000 files and form a union RDD of all the records and return it as unionbioSetId

run(){

```
JavaRDD<String> unionbioSetId = readDirectory(ctx, groupAID, groupBID);
JavaRDD<String> temp= unionbioSetId.coalesce(6, false);

JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple3<Double, Double, Double>> flatRDD = temp.flatMapToPair(
new PairFlatMapFunction<String, String, String>() {
return Arrays.asList(new Tuple2<String, String>(key,value));
}}).groupByKey().mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, Iterable<String>>, // input 
String, // K
Tuple3<Double, Double, Double> // V
>() {
public Tuple2<String, Tuple3<Double, Double, Double>> call(
Tuple2<String, Iterable<String>> value) { 
}).filter(new Function<Tuple2<String, Tuple3<Double, Double, Double>>, Boolean>() {
}});// group by key and map to pair,sort by key
}
String hadoopOutputPathAsString = directory; 
flatRDD.saveAsTextFile(hadoopOutputPathAsString);
}
```

}
///////////////
**num of executors:9
driver memory:2g
executor memory: 6g
execuotr cores: 12**

**My program is running slower than map/reduce(same code skeleton). Can any one help me in optimizing the above code skeleton to make it faster.**

Comment: The code you've provided is entirely unreadable. It is badly indented and parts are clearly missing. Braces don't match up. Can you please clean it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't call `coalesce`.** You don't need less partitions, you need more. You have 108 worker cores, but you only use 6 of them if you go with 6 partitions. A rule of thumb is you want at least **3 * `num_executors` * `cores_per_executor` = 324** partitions.

```
JavaRDD<String> temp = unionbioSetId.repartition(350);
```

Or just don't change the number of partitions at all. When the files are read, the data is partitioned by Hadoop splits. In many cases this gives a good layout, and you would avoid the cost of repartitioning.

**Read the files at once** instead of reading them separately and then taking their union: `sc.textFile("file1,file2,file3,...")` or `sc.textFile("dir/*")`. This may also make a performance difference.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have formatted the code for your reference. I have removed certain code form the skeleton as they are confidential. With the coalesce my program took 4 min to execute but with repartition it takes more more than 15 min. I cannot use sc.textFile("dir/*") because my each input file exists in a different path and i should not change it. So i have to read each file and convert it to RDD and then form a union of all RDD's which will give 80 million records of key value pair. If i go with .textfile default split my program runs into outofmemory error.

Comment: Huh, I wonder why it's running slower with more partitions... But regarding `sc.textFile`, you can give it a comma-separated list of file names. No guarantees that it will make it faster though.

Comment: yeah with more partitions it is utilizing all the executors properly but taking more time.  I am doubtful about coalesce and repartition API. with coalesce my program is super fast. Can i use coalesce instead of repartition and still get the same result?Thanks.

Comment: Bingo!! with comma-separated list of file names it works super fast than union(). from 5 minutes to 1 minute!! Thank you so much for the suggestion.